# Multiple condition AND in JOIN MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I'm having a problem constructing my SQL query. Suppose I have a table expert; for example:

```
+----+------------+-----------+
| id | first_name | last_name |
+----+------------+-----------+
|  6 | Ahmed      | Mouloud   |
|  7 | Alice      | Lanouix   |
+----+------------+-----------+
```

a table expert_competence which allow to join an expert to competence:

```
+----+---------------+-----------+
| id | competence_id | expert_id |
+----+---------------+-----------+
| 28 |             1 |         7 |
| 29 |             3 |         7 |
| 30 |             4 |         7 |
| 31 |             5 |         7 |
| 32 |            19 |         7 |
| 33 |            20 |         7 |
| 34 |             1 |         6 |
| 35 |             5 |         6 |
| 36 |             6 |         6 |
| 37 |            21 |         6 |
+----+---------------+-----------+
```

and a table competence:

```
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | name                                                                    |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | INSPECTEUR OPERATIONS AERIENNES                                         |
|  2 | INSPECTEUR OPERATIONS AERIENNES SAC MONACO                              |
|  3 | INSPECTEUR OPERATIONS AERIENNES DCA MAURICE                             |
|  4 | CONSULTING AUPRES D'UNE CAA      
  ...                                     |                                    
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

How can I make to get all experts who master the competence with id 1 AND 3 (NOT OR)?

I have tried this but it's doesn't work (to find all expert who master the competence 1 AND 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ex.* 
FROM expert ex 
LEFT JOIN expert_competence ec 
ON ec.expert_id = ex.id 
WHERE ec.competence_id = 1 
AND ec.competence_id = 3
```

I have tried also with this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ex.* 
FROM expert ex 
LEFT JOIN expert_competence ec 
ON ec.expert_id = ex.id 
WHERE ec.competence_id IN (1,3);
```

Result:

```
+----+-----------+------------+
| id | last_name | first_name |
+----+-----------+------------+
|  7 | Lanouix   | Alice      |
|  6 | Mouloud   | Ahmed      |
+----+-----------+------------+
```

Expected Results:

```
+----+------------+-----------+
| id | first_name | last_name |
+----+------------+-----------+
|  7 | Alice      | Lanouix   |
+----+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: @Ahmed If any expert has acquired competence from `1 to 8` does he count under expert?

Comment: you could do: where ec.competence.id IN (1,8)

Comment: You want a relational division. See  https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/

Comment: GROUP BY, HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT competence.id) >= 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have founded a working solution :

```
SELECT ex.*  FROM 
expert ex LEFT JOIN expert_competence ec 
ON ec.expert_id = ex.id 
WHERE ec.competence_id WHERE ec.competence_id = 1 
AND ex.id in (SELECT ex.id  FROM expert ex 
              LEFT JOIN expert_competence ec 
              ON ec.expert_id = ex.id 
              WHERE ec.competence_id = 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ex.*
FROM
    expert AS ex
    LEFT JOIN expert_competence AS ec ON ec.expert_id = ex.id
WHERE 
    ec.competence.id IN (1, 8)
```

By using `IN`, you can specify multiple possible criteria for a column.

Comment: This should not help, It will pull the expert though it doesn't have the competency, `IN (1,8)` is nothing but `IN (1 or 2 or 3 .. or 8)` basically OR operation and user must be looking for AND operator, all 1 to 8 should exists to consider an expert.

Comment: You mean an expert must posses 8 or more skills - or exactly 8 skills? ..and does it have to be these particular skills?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ex.* 
FROM expert_competence ec
LEFT JOIN  expert ex
ON ec.expert_id = ex.id 
WHERE ec.competence.id IN (1, 8)
```

Just noticed `ec.competence.id` is it really named after that in the table? FOr now I fixed some conditioning in the query and some table arrangements in your `JOIN` query.

Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: Sorry just an error when I written the query.The problem with "IN" is that it works like an OR.  And I need only the expert who masters the competence 1 AND 8. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From your provided input it's not clear what you're looking far, I'm assuming you're looking for something like this, I'm considering you have `competence_master` table which stores all the master id.

Using [All](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/all-subqueries.html) operator you can achieve the desired result. [Live Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/860de/2)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ex.* 
FROM expert ex 
LEFT JOIN expert_competence ec 
ON ec.expert_id = ex.id 
WHERE ec.competence_id >= 
ALL ( select distinct id from  competence_master);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ex.*
FROM
    expert AS ex
    LEFT JOIN expert_competence AS ec ON ec.expert_id = ex.id
WHERE 
    FIND_IN_SET(ec.competence.id,'1,8')
```